# get media image file by post_title

Tags: php, args, wordpress

All my media file images are named like 'icon_0001', 'icon_0002', 'icon_0003', 'illustration_0001', 'illustration_0002', 'illustration_0003' and so on, along with other image files like 'SummonClear', 'StunPowder', etc. I've checked this with the wordpress admin ui and also by var_dumping the attachments.

And now I am trying to retrieve the media file ID with the following code:

```
$post_name = 'illustration_30004';
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_title' => trim( $post_name ),
    'post_mime_type' => 'image/png',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    );


$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

foreach( $wp_query->posts as $image) {
    var_dump( $image );
    echo '<hr/>';

}
```

Yes, this is just a simple query code using `post_type = attachment`.
However, whatever name I give to `$post_name`, the query displays ALL image files in the media library, like below:

```
object(WP_Post)#1386 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(40735) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2014-10-08 10:22:04" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-10-08 10:22:04" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(11) "SummonClear" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "inherit" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(13) "summonclear-3" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2014-10-08 10:22:04" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-10-08 10:22:04" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(104) "http://101.251.201.22/digital-opal-mu/elin-expedition/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/assets/SummonClear2.png" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(10) "attachment" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" }

object(WP_Post)#1387 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(40734) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2014-10-08 10:22:04" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-10-08 10:22:04" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(11) "SummonChick" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "inherit" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(13) "summonchick-3" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2014-10-08 10:22:04" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-10-08 10:22:04" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(104) "http://101.251.201.22/digital-opal-mu/elin-expedition/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/assets/SummonChick2.png" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(10) "attachment" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" }

object(WP_Post)#1388 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(40733) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2014-10-08 10:22:04" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-10-08 10:22:04" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(10) "StunPowder" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "inherit" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(12) "stunpowder-3" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2014-10-08 10:22:04" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-10-08 10:22:04" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(103) "http://101.251.201.22/digital-opal-mu/elin-expedition/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/assets/StunPowder2.png" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(10) "attachment" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" }

object(WP_Post)#1389 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(40732) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2014-10-08 10:22:04" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-10-08 10:22:04" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(5) "Stomp" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "inherit" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(7) "stomp-3" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2014-10-08 10:22:04" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-10-08 10:22:04" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(98) "http://101.251.201.22/digital-opal-mu/elin-expedition/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/assets/Stomp2.png" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(10) "attachment" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" }

...and 900+ more of these.
```

I know I have a media file with the name 'illustration_30004' because below result is included in the 900+ results.

```
object(WP_Post)#1871 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(40973) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2014-10-07 03:38:14" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-10-07 03:38:14" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(18) "illustration_30004" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "inherit" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(18) "illustration_30004" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2014-10-07 03:38:14" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-10-07 03:38:14" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(110) "http://101.251.201.22/digital-opal-mu/elin-expedition/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/assets/illustration_30004.png" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(10) "attachment" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" }
```

So the question is...what is wrong with my query and why am I getting ALL media files instead of the `post_title` I want?

Added: one more thing though i'm not sure this is relevant - these media files are uploaded to wordpress but are not attached to any post yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong, thanks to the suggestion from Bizzkit. I should have used 'name' instead of 'post_title', as below:

```
/**
 * Get media image file by name
 */
function get_media_image( $image_name ) {

    $post_name = trim( $image_name );

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'name' => $post_name,
        'post_mime_type' => 'image/png',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
        );


    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $images = array();

    foreach( $wp_query->posts as $image) {
        $images[] = $image->guid;
    }

    if( sizeof( $images ) == 1 ) {
        return $images[0];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think 'post_title' is a valid argument. [Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters)

You can try:

'name' to look posts up by their slug
'p' to look them up by ID
's' to perform a keyword search

Comment: Bizzkit/ Thank you for the suggestion, but this is a media file and I don't think media files have 'slug'?

Comment: They do, you can see it by going to Library, then click on an attachment, then select either "View attachment page" or "Edit more details". You can see the slug in both - either in the URL of the attachment page or in the slug edit slot of the attachment editor page (same as on a post edit page). Let me know if this helps!